# my server will damage if i delete this infected files?

Tags: centos, malware, scanner, clamav

some spam scripts in my server (it send thousands of mails/hr) i did scan to my server CentOS7 + Virtualmin using clamav , and this is the reuslts :

```
/home/joudakpk/homes/info/Maildir/cur/1555410522.27486_0.ser.voceweb.com: Email.Phishing.VOF1-6314019-0 FOUND
/home/joudakpk/homes/info/Maildir/cur/1554693257.32497_0.ser.voceweb.com: Email.Trojan.Toa-5493309-0 FOUND
/var/lib/clamav/rfxn.hdb: YARA.Safe0ver_Shell__Safe_Mod_Bypass_By_Evilc0der_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/var/lib/clamav/rfxn.yara: {HEX}php.gzbase64.inject.452.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/var/lib/clamav/rfxn.ndb: YARA.Safe0ver_Shell__Safe_Mod_Bypass_By_Evilc0der_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/var/log/clamav/manual_clamscan.log: YARA.Safe0ver_Shell__Safe_Mod_Bypass_By_Evilc0der_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/var/spool/postfix/deferred/9/988795815AA: YARA.r57shell_php_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/local/maldetect/sigs/md5v2.dat: YARA.Safe0ver_Shell__Safe_Mod_Bypass_By_Evilc0der_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/local/maldetect/sigs/rfxn.hdb: YARA.Safe0ver_Shell__Safe_Mod_Bypass_By_Evilc0der_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/local/maldetect/sigs/rfxn.yara: {HEX}php.gzbase64.inject.452.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/local/maldetect/sigs/md5.dat: YARA.Safe0ver_Shell__Safe_Mod_Bypass_By_Evilc0der_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/local/maldetect/sigs/hex.dat: YARA.Safe0ver_Shell__Safe_Mod_Bypass_By_Evilc0der_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/local/maldetect/sigs/rfxn.ndb: YARA.Safe0ver_Shell__Safe_Mod_Bypass_By_Evilc0der_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/local/maldetect/logs/event_log: YARA.r57shell_php_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/local/maldetect/sess/quarantine.hist: YARA.r57shell_php_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/local/maldetect/sess/hits.hist: YARA.r57shell_php_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/local/maldetect/sess/session.190502-0005.4595: YARA.r57shell_php_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/local/maldetect/sess/session.hits.190502-0005.4595: YARA.r57shell_php_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/local/maldetect/sigs.old/md5v2.dat: YARA.Safe0ver_Shell__Safe_Mod_Bypass_By_Evilc0der_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/local/maldetect/sigs.old/rfxn.hdb: YARA.Safe0ver_Shell__Safe_Mod_Bypass_By_Evilc0der_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/local/maldetect/sigs.old/rfxn.yara: {HEX}php.gzbase64.inject.452.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/local/maldetect/sigs.old/md5.dat: YARA.Safe0ver_Shell__Safe_Mod_Bypass_By_Evilc0der_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/local/maldetect/sigs.old/hex.dat: YARA.Safe0ver_Shell__Safe_Mod_Bypass_By_Evilc0der_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/local/maldetect/sigs.old/rfxn.ndb: YARA.Safe0ver_Shell__Safe_Mod_Bypass_By_Evilc0der_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/local/maldetect/clean/gzbase64.inject.unclassed: {HEX}php.gzbase64.inject.452.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/share/clamav/rfxn.hdb: YARA.Safe0ver_Shell__Safe_Mod_Bypass_By_Evilc0der_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/share/clamav/rfxn.yara: {HEX}php.gzbase64.inject.452.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/usr/share/clamav/rfxn.ndb: YARA.Safe0ver_Shell__Safe_Mod_Bypass_By_Evilc0der_php.UNOFFICIAL FOUND

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 6139866
Engine version: 0.101.2
Scanned directories: 123063
Scanned files: 643152
Infected files: 28
Total errors: 13042
Data scanned: 130821.71 MB
Data read: 109355.80 MB (ratio 1.20:1)
Time: 20850.863 sec (347 m 30 s)
```

first : i changed all users Passwords , main passwords , disabled root login. second : i deleted "info" folder and info user.

now i don't know what i should to do ?

Comment: I would really strongly recommend that you read the answers at [How do I deal with a compromised server](https://serverfault.com/q/218005/267016) over on [SF] and act on them.

Answer (score 1):

I will reply here to make things a bit more easy to read.

Those files can be deleted. Then install *rkhunter*, this tool will scan your machine for probable modified binaries or bad things.

Then it doesn't mean your server will be clean. Under linux it's pretty easy to make nasty hidden things and you have to check your machine carefully. And by the way you also have to find how those guys could hack your server. If it's from a web page, you have to secure it to avoid them to come back. So, many things to check before to be "sure" your machine is clean

Comment: rkhunter results :

`System checks summary

 File properties checks...
 Files checked: 126
 Suspect files: 0

 Rootkit checks...
 Rootkits checked : 486
 Possible rootkits: 0

Applications checks...
 All checks skipped

 The system checks took: 2 minutes and 45 seconds

Info: End date is Fri May  3 13:27:08 CEST 2019`


also i plan to migirate to another Server with Cpanel/WHM but i want to make sure that this issue solved

Comment: Well, this is just a summary of your scan, we can't know is your server is clean or not or even if the "suspect" files are bad or not. And as I said to my last answer, it's pretty easy to hide bad things under linux. rkhunter is looking for "known" things but will not detect a crap home made script hidden in a home folder.

Comment: thank you ,, in your side what do you think i should to do ?

Comment: Well, if you have a clean full backup of the machine, I would use it to restore the server. If not and if the server is fairly easy to reinstall from zero, reinstall it. If it's complicated and long to reinstall (but then you should have backups...), try to clean it with the risk to keep bad files on it.

Comment: i did scan more times and results was 0 infected files, also i send one of the website backup (new backup after the issue) to scan it by All in One migration team (  wordpress migration plugin ) and it clear. also the spam attempts was stopped but i still see one attempts ( unknown sender to strange email ) every 30 min. or more

Comment: `May  4 10:50:47 server1 postfix/qmgr[13316]: 5537C581214: from=<>, size=2695, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May  4 10:50:47 server1 postfix/qmgr[13316]: 4AE815807B0: removed
May  4 10:50:47 server1 postfix/local[21445]: 5537C581214: to=<maat@server1.vateb.com>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0/0.02/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
May  4 10:50:47 server1 postfix/qmgr[13316]: 5537C581214: removed`

Comment: `May  4 10:50:47 server1 postfix/smtp[21443]: 4F0C5581138: to=<eiuseumsedenimqu@hotmail.com>, relay=hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.37.33]:25, delay=0.63, delays=0/0.02/0.46/0.15, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.37.33] said: 550 5.7.1 Unfortunately, messages from [173.249.46.176] weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list (S3150).  (in reply to MAIL FROM command))`

Comment: `May  4 10:50:47 server1 postfix/smtp[21443]: 4F0C5581138: lost connection with hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.37.33] while sending RCPT TO
May  4 10:50:47 server1 postfix/cleanup[21438]: E963A581135: message-id=<20190504085047.E963A581135@server1.vateb.com>`

Comment: Man, as I said before, you can try all the scanners or antivirus you want, none of them will detect a simple shell script looping and sending thousands of phishing email. It wont detect either a 2 lines script able to shred your entire disk. So, reinstall your machine from scratch, it's, in my opinion, the best thing to do now.